# Como sincronizar vários botões a um evento?

Tags: c#, winforms

Boa noite, meu professor de linguagem de programação pediu para que fizéssemos uma programa, que ao chamar o evento Form1_Load gerasse 200 botões, até ai eu fiz, mas eu queria implementar um função que o clicar em um botão, independente de qual ele trocasse de cor. Porém sem ter que adicionar os 200 botões no código, segue o código:

```
public partial class Form1 : Form
{
    Button[] btn = new Button[200];
    public Form1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        char letra = 'A';
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
            {
                btn[i] = new Button();
                btn[i].Name = letra.ToString() + j + 1;
                btn[i].Text = letra.ToString() + (j + 1);
                btn[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
                btn[i].Location = new Point(90 * (i + 1), 30 * (j + 1));
                Controls.Add(btn[i]);
            }
            letra++;
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O seu código está correto, o que faltou é especificar um evento que no momento do `Click`, pode alterar a cor do componente, exemplo:

```
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    char letra = 'A';
    for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
    {
        for (int j = 0; j < 20; j++)
        {
            btn[i] = new Button();
            btn[i].Name = letra.ToString() + j + 1;
            btn[i].Text = letra.ToString() + (j + 1);
            btn[i].BackColor = Color.Green;
            btn[i].Location = new Point(90 * (i + 1), 30 * (j + 1));
            btn[i].Click += Button_Click;
            Controls.Add(btn[i]);
        }
        letra++;
    }
}

private void Button_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    ((Button)sender).BackColor = Color.Red;
}
```

ou seja, na linha adicionada `btn[i].Click += Button_Click;` foi criado o evento. No evendo o `object sender` significa que no momento que clicar no botão é passado para essa variável o botão que foi clicado agora só dar um `cast` e utilizar `BackColor` e mudar a cor, nesse exemplo muda para vermelho.

Comment: Valeu mano, ajudou muito !